# How to scrape <div data-key " " > in R

Tags: r, rvest

I want to scrape the HTML text below using R. I know I can use <div Class=" " to target the data i need.

Example:

```
scrape_css_attr <- function(css, group, attribute, html){
  txt <- html %>%
    html_nodes(group) %>%
    lapply(. %>% html_nodes(css) %>% html_attr(attribute) %>% ifelse(identical(.,character(0)),NA,.)) %>%
    unlist()
  return(txt)
}

urls <- scrape_css_attr("a", "#w0", "href", html)
```

But my question is, how can I scrape the data-key?

```
<div data-key="34356"><a href="/storingen/34356-18-september-2020-defecte-trein-sittard-maastricht" class="disruption-list-item resolved" title="Sittard-Maastricht">
    <div class="disruption-icon">
        <img src="/images/disruptions/defective-stock.svg" alt="">    </div>
    <div class="disruption-content">
        <span class="disruption-line">Sittard-Maastricht</span>
                <br>
        <em>
            defecte trein        </em>     
        <div class="timestamp">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            11:32                -
                12:34                •
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                1 uur, 2 minuten                    </div>
    </div>
</a></div>
```

The website: https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/storingen

Answer (score 1):

If you meant you wanna get the data-key list, find the `<div>` tags that contain `data-key` attribute and extract them:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
last_page <- 5 # change it to 1655 to scrape all pages
datakeys <- 
  flatten_chr(map(
    1:last_page,
    function(i) {
      read_html(paste0("https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/storingen?page=", i)) %>% 
        html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@id='w0']/div[@data-key]") %>% 
        html_attr("data-key")
    }
  ))
```

Or you can scrape the data of those tags directly:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
last_page <- 5 # change it to 1655 to scrape all pages
data <- 
  map_dfr(
    1:last_page,
    function(i) {
      items <- read_html(paste0("https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/storingen?page=", i)) %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@id='w0']/div[@data-key]")
      print(i)
      data.frame(
        date = items %>% html_node(xpath = "(./preceding-sibling::h4)[last()]") %>% html_text(trim = T),
        datakey = items %>% html_attr("data-key"),
        link = paste0("https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/", items %>% html_node(xpath = "./a[1]") %>% html_attr("href")),
        title = items %>% html_node(xpath = "./descendant::div[@class='disruption-content']/descendant::span[@class='disruption-line']") %>% html_text(trim = T),
        description = items %>% html_node(xpath = "./descendant::div[@class='disruption-content']/descendant::em") %>% html_text(trim = T),
        timestamp = items %>% html_node(xpath = "./descendant::div[@class='timestamp']") %>% html_text(trim = T)
      )
    }
  )
```